# How to copy many files from AWS S3 in one call without recursion?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to copy many files (>10,000) from `aws s3`. This bucket contains hundreds of thousands of files and I do not want to download all of them. **This process needs to be repeated automatically/programmatically every hour, as new files come into the bucket frequently.**

The only supported ways that I can find to do this using native `awscli` parameters are:

1. Use the `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://the_bucket/ local_location` option. Because the bucket contains hundreds of thousands of files this process downloads many, many files I do not want, and is very slow.
2. Use `aws s3 sync`. This approach only downloads the files I want, but is very slow. If the bucket updates with only a few files `sync` has to check the **entire bucket** for new files. This is very slow.
3. Use `aws s3 ls s3://the_bucket/ local_location` to find all files in the bucket and compare to an index of files that I have previously downloaded that I do not want to download again. `aws s3 ls` is very fast, however, I have to the call `aws s3 cp s3://the_bucket/the_file local_location` **one by one** which is very slow.

**tl;dr**

How can I copy the many files I need from an `aws s3` bucket without using recursion (i.e. `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://the_bucket/ local_location` or calling `awscli` many times)?

Answer (score 2):

You are, indeed, in a difficult situation.

Once the number of objects in a bucket increases, it takes a long time to list them. The API call to list objects only returns 1000 objects at a time. Both the `aws s3 sync` and `aws s3 cp ...*` command need to list objects in order to copy them.

An alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing all objects, but this does not appear to meet your requirement to download new files every hour.

A more complex method (but one that will work) is to create an Amazon S3 Event whenever a new object is created. You can then process the event in one of two ways:

- Push the event into an **Amazon SQS queue**. Then, each hour, run a program that will process the messages in the queue and copy the files, *or*
- Trigger an **AWS Lambda function** for each event. The Lambda function can add details to a database, which can then be used each hour to obtain a list of files to copy.

Comment: John, you raise some good alternatives. However, I don't have permission to create lambda functions or to put anything on the SQS queue; I only have permission to list files and copy from the bucket. Thus my predicament.

Answer (score 0):

A practical workaround can be to create a directory with a timestamp every hour and store the new files in there. You then have to process only the latest timestamp directory in your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Under your specific circumstance ( very limited access to AWS resource ) and your observation

> Use aws s3 ls s3://the_bucket/ local_location to find all files in the bucket and compare to an index of files that I have previously downloaded that I do not want to download again. **aws s3 ls is very fast**, however, **I have to the call aws s3 cp s3://the_bucket/the_file local_location one by one which is very slow.**

I believe 3rd option is your best bet, with some remarks though

1/

> `aws s3 ls` is very fast

You may want to make sure that you get all the files you need and it is really as fast as you observed. When number of key returned is over 1000, you need to deal with marker/pagination to make more calls

2/

> I have to the call `aws s3 cp s3://the_bucket/the_file local_location`
>   one by one which is very slow.

As you are doing automations, It shouldn't be any slower than what your system is capable of. You will most likely be bottlenecked by your Internet bandwidth only. Consider doing multi-process if you have tons of small files, and config the [concurrent aspect of the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html) also

Comment: 1: I've tested `aws s3 ls --recursive` and it successfully recursively lists all of the elements of the buckets even over 1000 files even with just one call. 
2: I don't think this is correct. There is overhead with just calling the `awscli` program

Comment: Hmmm, for sure there would be some overhead calling aws-cli, especially when you have many very small files and calling it one after another. The thing is, you can spawn as many processes as you like until you run out of processing power. I'm pretty sure that 20 concurrent aws-cli procesesses would keep your bandwidth busy while the CPU stays pretty relaxed, still